# Use Teensy 3.2 in breadboard without soldering

Tags: soldering, breadboard, header, teensy

I bought a Teensy 3.2 board, and the package included some headers:
[image: Teensy & headers]

I want to use the Teensy in a breadboard, and so I plugged in the headers and put the entire thing in my breadboard:
[image: Teensy in breadboard]

The little holes in the Teensy and the header pins don't make a good connection, so I have to apply some sideways pressure to make it work. I guess the intention is that I solder those pins to the Teensy, right?

I don't have a soldering iron right now though and I would like to keep the Teensy in its current state, so is there another way to connect it to a breadboard? Thanks for the help!

Comment: dimensions get critical fitting square pegs in round holes, unless press fit type, solder ...or Swiss round contacts , which were not used here it seems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a set of press-fit headers (e.g. [these](http://suddendocs.samtec.com/catalog_english/ptt.pdf)) instead. The loops press against the sides of the holes in order to make a decent connection. Note that they may come loose when the board is removed from the breadboard though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have reliable connection soldering is the way to go.

For a few connections and for toying around put a piece of wire through the hole and twist the ends using pliers. It could leave some marks on the PCB though.

[image]